# How to transform form to array key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

How do I transform the form content into array key-value? This is one example that I tried:

```
 function formToArray(){
    var sAux=Array();
    var frm = document.getElementById("formUsuario");
    for (i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++) {

        //next line dont work
        sAux[frm.elements[i].name] = frm.elements[i].value;

    }
    alert(sAux);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use object instead of array.following should solve your problem.(assuming formUsuario is a form id). [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3kSL/)

```
function formToArray(){
    var sAux={};
    var frm = document.getElementById("formUsuario");
    for (i = 0; i < frm.length; i++) {

        //next line dont work
        sAux[frm[i].name] = frm[i].value;

    }
    alert(sAux);
}
```